# Ranking Multiple Values By Frequency in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, ranking

I am looking to rank the values in multiple columns based on how frequently a given value in a given column is associated with the ID. The example I have is as below. Here, given that age is 23 twice, income is $50,000 twice, and the gender is M twice, it stands to reason that the person associated with the ID is 23, has an income of $50,000 and is male. I need a function that can apply this 'frequency ranking' on ~150 columns like this in Pyspark.

[image]

I have tried writing this using the window function in Pyspark but that does not yield the expected result.

Comment: Show us the input and output as well